# Implementing onChanged of MapChangeListener - why this lambda

Tags: java, javafx, lambda, listener

In my JavaFX, I attempted to have an `ObservableMap<String, String>` and a `MapChangeListener` that listens to keys and values changes(adding/removing a key or the corresponding value) and then does its job.

To make the listener be effective, the method to implement is:

```
void onChanged(MapChangeListener.Change<? extends K,? extends V> change)
```

What I first did, with a lambda expression, that doesn't generate any error:

```
map.addListener((MapChangeListener.Change<? extends String, ? extends String> change) -> {
    //code here to implement onChange method
}
```

And here is what I discovered, that still doesn't generate any error:

```
map.addListener((MapChangeListener<String, String>) change -> {
    //code here to implement onChange method
}
```

Note the position of the round brackets in this two different examples. The second seems to me to be a cast, but I really don't understand why this second option works.
Can anyone explain me this, please?

P.S.: Actually, I came accross this because I was dealing with a
`ObservableMap<String, List<String>>`,
that is a multimap, and the first "way" of the two above didn't work (with the right adjustments). **/EDIT:** I tried again with the first "way" and actually it does work, there was an error on the code I didn't notice **END EDIT/**. Then I tried with the second option, and it did work, and I was dazed. Then I discovered this same "behaviour" with a simple map `<String, String>` and this question has arisen.

Comment: Gave you an extra example which would illustrate the differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two are equivalent. The first one, you are defining the parameter of the lambda expression - note that your bracket covers the whole change parameter. This allows the compiler to know which overload to match it against.

The second one is simply a cast. You are telling the compiler what kind of method signature to match this lambda against. `(MapChangeListener<String, String>)` casts the whole lambda expression into a `MapChangeListener`, so the compiler knows that it really is `addListener(MapChangeListener)`. Since you have defined the single parameter defined by `MapChangeListener`, the compiler doesn't complain that it is wrong either.

### Edit

Now that I have a bit more time, I would give you some concrete example that will help you understand a little more in depth.

```
public class Foo {
    public final void bar(IntfA a) {}
    public final void bar(IntfB b) {}
    public final void bar(IntfC c) {}
}

@FunctionalInterface
public interface IntfA {
    void doSomething(Double a);
}

@FunctionalInterface
public interface IntfB {
    void doSomething(Integer a);
}

@FunctionalInterface
public interface IntfC {
    void doSomething(Double a);
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo();

        foo.bar(a -> {}); // Ambiguous
        foo.bar((Integer a) -> {}); // Okay, this is IntfB
        foo.bar((Double a) -> {}); // Ambiguous between IntfA and IntfC
        foo.bar((IntfC) a -> {}); // No longer ambiguous since you specified that it's IntfC
        foo.bar((IntfC) (a, b) -> {}); // Method signature does not match IntfC
    }
}
```

### Edit 2

It seems like you need a little more help here.

When you define a method `bar(IntfA)`, you are expecting an object of `IntfA`, regardless whether `IntfA` is an interface type or a class type.

Then, lambda expressions are just compile-time convenient syntax. When I write `foo.bar((Integer a) -> {})`, the compiler will eventually turn it into Java bytecodes (within .class file) that is equivalent to this:

```
foo.bar(new IntfB() {
    public void doSomething(Integer a) {
    }
});
```

That equivalence is what we call [Anonymous Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).

The biggest and possibly only difference in using lambda is, it makes your code shorter. Sometimes it makes your code more readable, sometimes it makes your code less readable.

Since lambda reduces the amount of things that you need to type out, it is very easy to have a lambda expression that is ambiguous for the compiler when there are overload methods like in the example. Remember that the compiler needs to figure out which overload first, then it will help you to instantiate the object for you.

When you write `foo.bar((Double a) -> {})`, the compile notices that you have a lambda expression that takes in one `Double` parameter and returns nothing. It will then look at the three overloads of `bar()`. It notices that both `bar(IntfA)` and `bar(IntfC)` takes in a functional interface, and both interface's method takes in one `Double` parameter and returns nothing. At this point, the compiler is not sure whether it should generate bytecodes equivalent to which two set of codes:

Choice 1:

```
foo.bar(new IntfA() {
    public void doSomething(Double a) {
    }
});
```

Choice 2:

```
foo.bar(new IntfC() {
    public void doSomething(Double a) {
    }
});
```

If you write `foo.bar((IntfC) a -> {})`, you are already hinting to the compiler that you want it to match `foo.bar(IntfC)` overload. The compiler sees that you have one parameter of unknown type, but since you have already tell it to match to `IntfC`, it will assume that parameter is `Double`.

Now to the last part, calling `foo.bar(IntfA)` doesn't automatically call the `doSomething(Double a)` method specified by `IntfA`. In my example the `bar()` methods did nothing, but normally people would write something useful.

Example again:

```
public final void bar(IntfB obj) {
    if (obj == null)
        System.out.println("I was waiting for an IntfB object but I got nothing!");
    else
        obj.doSomething(100);
}

foo.bar((Integer a) -> {
    System.out.println("I got " + a + " marks for my exam!");
});
```

This causes "I got 100 marks for my exam!" to be printed on the console.

Comment: Ok, this made me understand more, really. But I have a question. Whenever I see this, like in your example, I should expect to have `a1.doSomething(a2)` in the body of `bar` method, where to distinguish `a1` is of type `IntfA` and `a2` of type `Integer`. Am I right?

Comment: @Kenna I don't understand your question. It is impossible to have `a1.doSomething(a2)`

Comment: No, I meant that `foo.bar((Integer a) -> {})` gives the implementation of `doSomething(Integer a)` and then `bar(IntfA a)` is called. Now I should expect that inside `bar` I have a call to `doSomething(Integer a)`. But since the arguments of `doSomething(Integer a)` and `bar(IntfA a)` have the same name `a`, I wanted to distinguish and I said `a1` and `a2`. I just meant that I should expect to have a call of `doSomething` inside `bar`, otherwise `(Integer a) -> {}` would be uneffective because it is not called inside `bar`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much Jai! Especially the last part was of my interest and you made me understand better. Infact, what I was meaning in my comments was that normally inside `bar`-like method there is a call to the `doSomething`-like method (that is implemented with the lambda or method reference or anonymous class), but if there isn't, `doSomething` method is not called (but is implemented).

Comment: @Kenna It's always nice to see that people are trying to understand. Some people just learn how to copy the right things and paste at the right place - probably works once or twice, not always.

Comment: Yes! You've got that right! Thank you so much again, Jai.

Answer (score 1):

Lambda in reality doesn't require its type to be expressed unless there is an ambiguity.

If you would not type `change` it would conflict with `addListener(InvalidationListener)` that has the same argument length. There are 2 ways of solving this, either by explicitly expressing the type (your first snippet) or by directing the compiler to the correct overload (second), which has nothing to do with lambda semantics.

To reiterate the second point, say you have

```
void print(String s)
```

and

```
void print(Integer i)
```

calling

`print(null)` would cause an ambiguity. The solution is `print((String)null)` which is of course not a type cast, as null has no type, but rather a compiler note.